# Skip a row in list view

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I guess `getView()` is called for each item of the list, but my question is, Can we not show the row if data associated with that row is null. I want to do this inside `getView ()` only.

For Example:

If the alerts for a person whose name is to be shown in list view are null.I don't want to display that person's name in list view.

Comment: why dont You filter the person before sending it to listview?

Comment: Yea i have done that..but I want to know is there a way we can do this inside getView()..?

Comment: you can not. You have to filter values before you submit your adapter to the listview

Comment: try setting convertview as null when u return the view

Comment: @Raghav: U got the answer juss show wat will be the last line of code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the [visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) of that row to "gone" in the last line before returning the View - that should work for you.

Edit: Be sure to set visibility to visible if the content is not null - otherwise all the views will become "gone" as the ListView reuses views.

```
myView.setVisibility((myData == null) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I dont think so.coz each row in list view has same id so it will set the visibility of all above rows to gone.

Comment: That's not correct - you just have to check for each row if the content is null or not and set the visibility to visible or gone.

Comment: You're welcome :) We're using that in our own projects, too :)

Comment: Can You tell me ...what is notifyDataSetChanged() for..?Willl it be applicable here.?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is used for telling the adapter that the views should be renewed (per example if the data in the adapter dynamically changes).

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt :Please share what will be the last line of code?

Comment: if((list.get(position).get("alerts")).isEmpty()){
   holder.txtFirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   
  }
  else
  holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get("firstName").toString() +"_____"+ map.get("lastName").toString());

Comment: I've added a possible last line before returning the View.

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt :The that row will become invisible or some other items will show?

Comment: Your code would only set the TextView's visibility to gone - my code would set the parent's View's visibility to gone. Furthermore I'd avoid checking for isEmpty() and I'd do it myself via == null || .equals("");

Comment: Hey can u givee me an exmaple showing the working of notifyDataSetChanged()..?

Comment: Check this topic at Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426

Comment: i think this is not the best solution for this purpose. just try to set your specific condition and increase your position number in getView.

Comment: Tried this solution. It creates blank places in the list

Answer (score 1):

Hi Pals I tried setting the visibility to invisible but still i can see an empty row in a listview so i change a little bit and it worked according to my need so it worth sharing if someone needs similar result like mine.

I am using **List**  as source my requirement was to skip few applications so what i did was i removed that application from the **List** and **notified Data set change**

```
public AppListAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> appList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appList = appList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        localStorage = new LocalStorage(context);
        pm = context.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
              convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.applist_item, parent, false);
            // Other lines of code
        if(appName.length()==0 || getItem(position).packageName.equals("package.name.to.skip")) {
              appList.remove(position);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    return convertView;
}
```

**Lines of Concern**

> appList.remove(position);
>   notifyDataSetChanged();

Your suggestions and corrections are always welcome.
AzmatHunzai